# JDBC Connectivity thru Java to Teradata

Tags: java, teradata

I am getting an `Null` pointer exception while connecting to `Teradata` through Java method using `Teradata` driver:

```
DriverManager.getConnection()
```

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: I suggest you ask Teradata support. If they don't know, no-one does.

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: You need some connection url right? You have to pass this inside **getConnection()** method or create object for DriverManager & set the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below codes & follow their reference docs [Teradata Docs](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/frameset.html)

```
Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
String url=jdbc:teradata://DatabaseServerName
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(connection url);
```

Answer (score 0):

First load these two jar files (JDBC driver):
1) tdgssconfig
2) terajdbc4

And then use below code to connect to the teradata server :

```
Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
```